# GPG keyserver that can directly import-export keys using hkp

Tags: gpg

I need to create next type of service: people from "outside" (by using some pre-created software) have to create gpg keys, which they have to use to sign documents. Users have to send to us pubkeys as files. After that step users have to send to us their signed files, signed by these keys.

So, on our "side" we have to set up some kind of keyserver, which has to import keys from users into it's own database, store them and have to have some API to communicate with outer world. In other words, I need to send (upload) user's keys directly to keyserver, and need functionality, provided by GPG.

As I understand, for example, SKS server has similar functionality. But it can't (as I understand) directly import keys as a files into it's database. I can't get files from it. Only `--import` `--export` from some host. This is only can be done using "local" gpg-base and then sending them to server.

So, the question: are there any kind of servers that can directly import-export-manipulate keys using, for example, hkp:// protocol?

As for example, I have to do next steps:

`gpg --import --keyserver IP gpg-file.pub
gpg --export --keyserver IP <Fingerprint or ID or ...>
gpg --disable --keyserver IP <Fingerprint>
gpg --enable --keyserver IP <Fingerprint>
gpg --revoke --keyserver IP <Fingerprint>
gpg --list-keys --keyserver IP <Fingerprint>
...`

P.S. Server has to be on Linux

Comment: I don't see anything which would actually require a keyserver in your question. Do users need to be able to obtain each other's public keys? If not, I don't think it's actually a keyserver you are looking for.

Comment: Users have to work only with their keys. The problem is, that such keys will be dozens of thousands. I'm afraid, that simple "keyrings", stored in `~/.gpg` and wrapper software, manipulating keys, would be too "thick" task.